# Check if a string has a certain value inside a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with python3 and I have a file (file.conf) where I have some variables.

The file.conf looks like this:

```
varx=true
vary=30015
```

varx can either be true or false (only).
vary must be a numeric value between 30000 and 30099.

What would be the best way to create a small script to check if both vars exist and are well defined?

Note: I must get all the errors, if there are errors in both vars.

Comment: Please, share your attempts and what didn't work for you

Comment: As far as varx I used if to check if varx equals true or false. Has for vary I am not sure how to do it, has I must capture the numbers after the equal (=) and then check if the number is between 30000 and 30099. That´s why I posted this. Could you be so kind to help here please?

Comment: You can edit your question to include the code that you've tried. You can capture the value for `vary` the same way you captured the value for `varx`.

Comment: @fr0zt the numerical value can be at the endpoints or not?

Comment: If the file is in a well defined format, the best way is to user a parser for that format and then check the resulting object if those key/value pairs exist and whether they satisfy the conditions. Relying on pure string operations can be brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution printing all errors:

```
with open("file.conf") as f:
    data = {k: v for k, _, v in (line.strip().partition("=") for line in f)}

if data["varx"] not in {"true", "false"}:
    print("varx must be true or false")

try:
    value = data["vary"] = int(data["vary"])
except ValueError:
    print("vary must be an integer")
else:
    if value < 30_000 or value > 30_099:
        print("vary Value must be between 30000 and 30099")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module.

But it wouldn't work for your `file.conf` though you'll have to modify it making a section, as described in the [quick-start](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#quick-start) official documentation.

You can use it as follows:

```ini
;; confs.ini
[init_vars] ;;name of section
varx=false
vary=30070
```

In the python script:

```
import configparser
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read("confs.ini") #replace with name of file
section_selected = "init_vars"

#raises exception if is not valid boolean
parser.getboolean(section_selected,"varx") 

#raises exception if is not int in the range
assert 0 <= parser.getint(section_selected,"vary") - 3e4 <= 99,"vary should be an int within range 30000-30099"
```

is always good practice to do tests for your code so here's some testing script that i did some time ago:

```
import configparser
import sys
import ctypes

def ANSII():...
if sys.platform=='win32':
    def ANSII():
        k = ctypes.windll.kernel32
        k.SetConsoleMode(k.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
        print("\033[33m[!] System ANSII Characters enabled.\033[0m")

def init_tests(tests:list[callable]):
    ANSII()
    def test(passed:bool,n_:int):
        if passed:
            print(f"\033[32mTest {n_} passed ✅")
            return
        print(f"\033[31mTest {n_} failed ❌")
        return 1
    res = []
    for i,_t in enumerate(tests):
        res.append(test(_t(),i))
    sys.stdout.write("\033[0m")
    return not any(res)# returns the validity of all the tests

parser = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
parser.read("file.conf")
tests = (
lambda:parser.getboolean("DEFAULT","varx"),
lambda:0 < parser.getint("DEFAULT","vary") - 3e4 < 99
)
init_tests(tests)
```

The output given a file `file.conf` with:

```
[DEFAULT]
varx=true
vary=30015
```

is:

```
[!] System ANSII Characters enabled. #this is actually yellow
Test 0 passed ✅ #this text is green
Test 1 passed ✅ #also this is green
```

You can't see the colors but in the terminal they show up, here's a screenshot from cmd:
[image]

Comment: This file can't be modified as it is being used by other scripts... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using strtobool and some manual validation:

```
# Casue strtobool is deprecated :-(
def strtobool(s):
    if s.lower() in ['y', 't', 'true', '1', 'yes', 'on']:
        return True
    elif s.lower() in ['n', 'f', 'false', '0', 'no', 'off']:
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid truth value %r' % (s,))

with open("file.conf") as f:
    data = {k: v for k, _, v in (line.strip().partition("=") for line in f)}

try:
    data["varx"] = strtobool(data["varx"])
    value = data["vary"] = int(data["vary"])
    if value < 30_000 or value > 30_099:
        raise ValueError("Value must be between 30000 and 30099")
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    exit(1)
```

Different `strtobool` implementation:

```
import configparser

def strtobool(s):
    try:
        return configparser.ConfigParser.BOOLEAN_STATES[s.lower()]
    except KeyError as e:
        raise ValueError('Not a boolean: %s' % s) from e
```

Comment: **NOTE**: the disutils package is deprecated and it will be removed in Python 3.12

Comment: @XxJames07- reimplemented strtobool :-(

Comment: in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool).

> True values are y, yes, t, true, on and 1; false values are `n, no, f, false, off` and `0`. Raises ValueError if val is anything else.

Comment: @XxJames07- yeah, fixed. I'm so sad it's deprecated. Was a lovely function. I need to write a eulogy.

Comment: *varx can either be true or false (only)*. Why complicate things? This should just be 3 lines of code.

Comment: This approach seems to work however if both vars are not ok, I only get a error message for the first one. Not bolean. I'd like to get all the messages outputed please

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution using `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd


#Read from .conf file to a dataframe :

df = pd.read_csv('test.conf', sep='=', header=None, names=['key', 'value'])

# This 2 lines are just for visualy observing the dataframe 
# if you are using a notebook without "print"
print(df)
print('__'*8)


#First line below checks if there are any missing variable in the "value" column of the dataframe:

if df['value'].isnull().values.any():
    print('There is missing data')
else:
    print('No missing data')
    if df['value'][0] == 'True':        
        if 30000 <= int(df['value'][1]) <= 30999 :
            print('Everything is ok!')
            # after this point you can add your own tasks / functions if everything is ok
            # ...
        else:
            print('Var_y is out of range!')
     
    elif not 30000 <= int(df['value'][1]) <= 30999 :
        print('Both Var_x is not True! and Var_y is out of range!')        
    else:
        print('Var_x is not True!')
```

Will give you a nice result like this (tested from my terminal):

```
     key  value
0  var_x   True
1  Var_y  30054
________________
No missing data
Everything is ok!
```

or this :

```
     key  value
0  var_x   True
1  Var_y  40054
________________
No missing data
Var_y is out of range!
```

There is much room to play with this code...